# Virtual functions causing link errors

Tags: c++, qt, kde-plasma

I am struggling with an issue while I am using external .h files in my project.

I am using Qt5 with MSVC2012. In my main file, I am including a header file from a KDE application. I put some INCLUDEPATH in the .pro file to link correctly.

The piece of code I am in trouble with is the following:

```
main.cpp
...
#include <Doc.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
...
```

The **Doc.h** belongs to the KDE application source code. Including that file includes many other files in several directories in the KDE application source code.

Currently, the **KUndo2Stack.h** and the **KUndo2Stack.cpp** files are the files I am struggling with since three days now.

When I run QMake and compile, I get a link 2001 errors due to unresolved externals with virtual functions in the **KUndo2QStack** class defined and implemented in those files. Here is an extract:

```
#ifndef QT_NO_UNDOSTACK

class KUNDO2_EXPORT KUndo2QStack : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
//    Q_DECLARE_PRIVATE(KUndo2QStack)
    Q_PROPERTY(bool active READ isActive WRITE setActive)
    Q_PROPERTY(int undoLimit READ undoLimit WRITE setUndoLimit)

public:
    explicit KUndo2QStack(QObject *parent = 0);
    virtual ~KUndo2QStack();
    void clear();

    void push(KUndo2Command *cmd);

    bool canUndo() const;
    bool canRedo() const;
    QString undoText() const;
    QString redoText() const;

    int count() const;
    int index() const;
    QString actionText(int idx) const;
    QString text(int idx) const;

#ifndef QT_NO_ACTION
    QAction *createUndoAction(QObject *parent) const;
    QAction *createRedoAction(QObject *parent) const;
#endif // QT_NO_ACTION

    bool isActive() const;
    bool isClean() const;
    int cleanIndex() const;

    void beginMacro(const QString &text);
    void endMacro();

    void setUndoLimit(int limit);
    int undoLimit() const;

    const KUndo2Command *command(int index) const;

public Q_SLOTS:
    void setClean();
    virtual void setIndex(int idx);
    virtual void undo();
    virtual void redo();
    void setActive(bool active = true);

Q_SIGNALS:
    void indexChanged(int idx);
    void cleanChanged(bool clean);
    void canUndoChanged(bool canUndo);
    void canRedoChanged(bool canRedo);
    void undoTextChanged(const QString &undoActionText);
    void redoTextChanged(const QString &redoActionText);

private:
    // from QUndoStackPrivate
    QList<KUndo2Command*> m_command_list;
    QList<KUndo2Command*> m_macro_stack;
    int m_index;
    int m_clean_index;
    KUndo2Group *m_group;
    int m_undo_limit;

    // also from QUndoStackPrivate
    void setIndex(int idx, bool clean);
    bool checkUndoLimit();

    Q_DISABLE_COPY(KUndo2QStack)
    friend class KUndo2Group;
};

class KUNDO2_EXPORT KUndo2Stack : public KUndo2QStack
{
public:
    explicit KUndo2Stack(QObject *parent = 0);

    // functions from KUndoStack
    QAction* createRedoAction(KActionCollection* actionCollection, const QString& actionName = QString());
    QAction* createUndoAction(KActionCollection* actionCollection, const QString& actionName = QString());
};

#endif // QT_NO_UNDOSTACK
```

Note that the unresolved links occur only for virtual functions. Those functions are implemented as it follows:

```
KUndo2QStack::~KUndo2QStack()
{
#ifndef QT_NO_UNDOGROUP
    if (m_group != 0)
        m_group->removeStack(this);
#endif
    clear();
}

void KUndo2QStack::undo()
{
    if (m_index == 0)
        return;

    if (!m_macro_stack.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning("KUndo2QStack::undo(): cannot undo in the middle of a macro");
        return;
    }

    int idx = m_index - 1;
    m_command_list.at(idx)->undo();
    setIndex(idx, false);
}

void KUndo2QStack::redo()
{
    if (m_index == m_command_list.size())
        return;

    if (!m_macro_stack.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning("KUndo2QStack::redo(): cannot redo in the middle of a macro");
        return;
    }

    m_command_list.at(m_index)->redo();
    setIndex(m_index + 1, false);
}

void KUndo2QStack::setIndex(int idx)
{
    if (!m_macro_stack.isEmpty()) {
        qWarning("KUndo2QStack::setIndex(): cannot set index in the middle of a macro");
        return;
    }

    if (idx < 0)
        idx = 0;
    else if (idx > m_command_list.size())
        idx = m_command_list.size();

    int i = m_index;
    while (i < idx)
        m_command_list.at(i++)->redo();
    while (i > idx)
        m_command_list.at(--i)->undo();

    setIndex(idx, false);
}
```

I have turned this question upside down looking for answers on the web and the only time I got something was when I deleted the word virtual off all the related functions. It cancelled the errors but **I got an unresolved link2019 error with the destructor** of the class **KUndo2Stack** (see the code above). The destructor I am talking about is the default one, you won't see any definition or implementation of it.

I need some help to understand what is really going on and how to fix it.

Thanks!

**Update**

The exact error messages are:

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl KUndo2QStack::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@KUndo2QStack@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl KUndo2QStack::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@KUndo2QStack@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl KUndo2QStack::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@KUndo2QStack@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl KUndo2QStack::setIndex(int)" (?setIndex@KUndo2QStack@@UEAAXH@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl KUndo2QStack::undo(void)" (?undo@KUndo2QStack@@UEAAXXZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void __cdecl KUndo2QStack::redo(void)" (?redo@KUndo2QStack@@UEAAXXZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __cdecl KUndo2Stack::~KUndo2Stack(void)" (__imp_??1KUndo2Stack@@UEAA@XZ) referenced in function "public: virtual void * __cdecl KUndo2Stack::`scalar deleting destructor'(unsigned int)" (??_GKUndo2Stack@@UEAAPEAXI@Z)

debug\whitehall_0_2.exe:-1: error: LNK1120: 7 unresolved externals
```

**Update**

After I added **Q_OBJECT** into the KUndo2Stack class, the link errors related to the qmetaobject of KUndo2QStack disappeared. The same errors appeared related to the **KUndo2Stack** class this time

```
main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct QMetaObject const * __cdecl KUndo2Stack::metaObject(void)const " (?metaObject@KUndo2Stack@@UEBAPEBUQMetaObject@@XZ)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual void * __cdecl KUndo2Stack::qt_metacast(char const *)" (?qt_metacast@KUndo2Stack@@UEAAPEAXPEBD@Z)

main.obj:-1: error: LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual int __cdecl KUndo2Stack::qt_metacall(enum QMetaObject::Call,int,void * *)" (?qt_metacall@KUndo2Stack@@UEAAHW4Call@QMetaObject@@HPEAPEAX@Z)
```

The other errors stayed the same.

Comment: What about reporting the *exact* error message?

Comment: What if you try to add `Q_OBJECT` macro to your `KUndo2Stack` class too, run qmake and build again?